# How to load/include projects from submodule Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-project

If I want to to combine two (or more) sbt projects (e.g. include one in the other)
**without** publish-local.

folder structure:

```
/ComboProject
    build.sbt
    /project
        Build.scala 
    /Project1
        build.sbt
        /project
            Build.scala #this includes lazy val p1
    /Project2
        build.sbt
        /project
            Build.scala #this includes lazy val p21, p22, p23, p24
```

The nested `Build.scala` gets ignored by sbt, however do they contain the project description and more importantly the build settings.
How can I import/make them visible at the `ComboProject` level **without** copy-pasting them into the top-level `Build.sbt`.

The same problem appears when including once project inside the other one.

```
/Project1 #make Project2 modules visible here
    build.sbt
    /project
        Build.scala #this includes lazy val p1
    /Project2
        build.sbt
        /project
            Build.scala #this includes lazy val p21, p22, p23, p24
```

Thanks a lot,
this would make it a lot easier to depend on fast evolving dependencies.

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html

Comment: As far as I know, project/Build.scala files cannot be nested. So you'd have to move them all to the top-level project folder.